# Parse : filter on string to pointer field in ios

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have two classes named classA and classB. classB has a field named "col1" of type pointer   < classA >. classB has some of objects of classA (user's liked object). I want to retrieve all objects of classA that are not contained in classB. classA has a field named "col1" with string type.

```
Code: following code returns no objects

PFQuery *qUserdata = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PFClassB];
[qUserdata         selectKeys:@[@“col1”]];
[qUserdata         whereKey:@"user_id"    equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
PFQuery *query    = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PFClassA];
[query  whereKey:@"objectId"  matchesKey:@"col1" inQuery: qUserdata];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) { 
            //——
}];
```

Can anyone figure out what is the problem with above code ?

Comment: If you say you find nothing, you mean that `[objects count]` in your block is `0`?

Comment: yes [objects count] returns 0

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if the following code works for you.

```
//Gets all the names 
PFQuery *classB = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PFClassB];
[classB selectKeys:@[@"col1"]];
[classB whereKey:@"user_id" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

//Find rows not in classB
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PFClassA];
[query  whereKey:@"objectId" doesNotMatchKey:@"col1" inQuery: classB];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) { 
        //——
}];
```

Comment: No luck. I searched more and find that what I needs is not possible with single match query.